# How to detect the shutdown of a php cronjob, when the server reboots

Tags: php, server, cron, shutdown

Within the framework of the development of a CMS type application, I use a periodic script with php because I cannot use crontab, not being an administrator of the server.

This pseudocronjob is working well. Without going into details, it looks like this   :

```
public function activateCron()
{
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    $time_sleep = 600;
    
    
    while ($this->IsStopCron() == 1) {
        sleep($time_sleep);
        exec('php ExecCron.php');
    }
}
```

The problem, however, is that if the server reboots, it stops.

I don't think there is a way to restart it automatically (besides that doesn't seem like a good idea to me), but I would still like to know a way to detect when the server stops, for example to send a mail automatically to ask the server administrator to restart it.

In my google searches I found register_shutdown_function, but I'm not sure if that fixes my problem or how. In any case it was not successful when I tried to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a personal crontab? Unless the administrator explicitly forbids that in the "cron.deny" file, that should be possible.

Comment: I don't know if I have permission to do this. And to be honest I don't know cron very well ^^ This maybe? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: If you **don't** have permission, the system **won't let you.** So you might as well try it and see. It's a minor item that most admins forget about entirely, so you are most likely allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`register_shutdown_function` likely won't be a reliable way to do this. Perhaps [`pcntl_signal`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php#example-3286) would work in detecting a clean server restart, assuming the system is configured to allow the services some time to wind down cleanly, but that still wouldn't help if there was say, a crash.

---

Personally i would think that auto-restarting it actually *is* the way to go; though of course PHP by itself doesn't offer any mechanic for that.

One possible method to approach that though, could be to piggyback web requests. That way, when the server has restarted, the very first time somebody visits your site, it would trigger your code and (re)start the php-cli process as you do in the code above.

---

Another avenue that *may* be an option if the server is running linux/systemd (which is common); Seeing as you are allowed to start `php-cli` processes with `exec('php ExecCron.php');`, you may also be able to run `systemctl --user`. If systemd `linger`ing is enabled on a multi-user system, [it allows users to define "services"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#Writing_user_units) there, that will be started on boot (or run at specific times or timeintervals; just like cronjobs).

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, I'll look that way.

Comment: Indeed, by putting a request "cron is supposed to be activated" and by comparing the timer of the last cron with the current timer, we detect that the cron has stopped and therefore we can restart it automatically as soon as the 1st visitor comes on the site. The concern is that if no one comes, the cron can remain disabled for a long time, but the nature of my CMS means that this can be problematic. There is no way to detect when the server restarts in PHP?

Comment: For exec() it was as part of presenting the problem, but in reality I don't use it.

Comment: There's many ways to detect it, but not from within the context of a webrequest. Most hosting providers offer access to either cronjobs and/or webhooks or a basic ssh shell, or similar mechanics; php-fpm doesn't actually read any of your code until there is a request. -- though i do have to wonder, if noone might visit your site, is the cronjob really important during that downtime ? surely there isn't any new data arriving and thus nothing to process ?

Comment: The cron allows to record weather data coming from an API in a database to then perform climatology, so it is important and there is no need for visitors.

Comment: I see, but isn't it worth getting some webhosting that does offer the needed features then?

Comment: I can't know in advance, what will be the architecture of the server, of the person, who will use my application, because I am working on a CMS (which installs as wordpress). So, in principle, it should work on the simplest web architecture possible.

Comment: I see, i don't know of many webhosts that do not offer such features though; even the simplest one-man-hostingcompany hosts tend to have CPanel or the like in my experience, which come with cron for users by default ; but of course ymmv.